# Display custom object and fields with Visualforce

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

I have a custom object called Conference. I need to create a simple visualforce page that displays all records of Conference including the following details per Conference: Name, City, State, Start Date, End Date, Expected Attendess, and Actual Enrolled. I built this with standard Salesforce.com admin point-and-click, and they all display perfectly in a report I created with point-and-click.

With the following code I'm getting this error: 
Error: Unknown property 'Conference__cStandardController.conference'

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"    
 standardController="Conference__c" recordsetVar="conf">

   <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.styles, 'styles.css')}"/>
   <h1>Conference Details</h1> 

   <apex:form>
      <apex:dataTable value="{!Conference__c}" var="confItem" rowClasses="odd,even"> 

         <apex:column headerValue="Conference Name">
             <apex:outputField value="{!confItem.Name}"/>
         </apex:column> 

         <apex:column headerValue="City">
             <apex:outputText value="{!confItem.City__c}"/>
         </apex:column>

         <apex:column headerValue="State">
             <apex:outputText value="{!confItem.Location_State__c}"/>
         </apex:column>

         <apex:column headerValue="Start Date">
             <apex:outputText value="{!conference.Start_Date__c}"/>
         </apex:column>

         <apex:column headerValue="End Date">
             <apex:outputText value="{!conference.End_Date__c}"/>
         </apex:column>

         <apex:column headerValue="Technologies">
             <apex:outputText value="{!conference.Technologies__c}"/>
         </apex:column>  

         <apex:column headerValue="Expected">
             <apex:outputText value="{!conference.Number_of_Attendees_Expected__c}"/>
         </apex:column> 

         <apex:column headerValue="Currently Enrolled">
             <apex:outputText value="{!conference.Enrolled_Attendees__c}"/>
         </apex:column>  

     </apex:dataTable>
  </apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You already refered sObject Conference__c to conf.
Therefore in your dataTable you should write your code like this:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!conf}" var="confItem" rowClasses="odd,even"> 
<apex:column headerValue="Conference Name">
         <apex:outputField value="{!confItem.Name}"/>
     </apex:column>
and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

[`<apex:enhancedList>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm) might be your new best friend.

But if you want to keep the code you have so far you'd need to loop (meaning reference it in dataTable/pageBlockTable/repeat) over the variable name you've chosen as the "recordsetvar" attribute. Check out [this link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_controller_sosc_list_views.htm) for more info.

Something like that should work:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"    
standardController="Conference__c" recordSetVar="conferences">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!conferences}" var="c">
            <apex:column value="{!c.Name}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```